# Call to undefined method in class even when it is defined

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, codeigniter-2

I am getting the following error message turning up in my apache error logs:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method MyWebsite\Model\ContentMedia::getImagePath() in /var/www/www.website.com/application/libraries/MyWebsite/Model/ContentVersion.php on line 544

On line 544 of `ContentVersion.php` the call is made:

```
$cm->getImagePath('img', 'small');
```

The `ContentMedia` class extends another class called `Model` that *does* have that method:

```
class ContentMedia extends \MyWebsite\Model{
```

... the `Model` class:

```
namespace MyWebsite;

class Model{

    public function getImagePath($field, $size = null){

        ...
    }
```

I get this error show up every now and then in the log files, so it may be one particular instance where a user comes across this, but I don't know where. This method is used throughout the site and it works. If the method is definitely defined how can this error be thrown?

I thought about checking the access logs to match an exact requested URL to the timestamp of the error, but the access logs are insanely large of course, so any advice as to how to output just a chunk of time from a large access log would be amazing.

I am using Doctrine 2 and Codeigniter 2.

Comment: Can you show the code where you instance the `$cm` object?

Comment: Actually it comes from a Doctrine query. Then I'm iterating over the ContentMedia relations with a simple for loop: foreach($this->contentMedia as $cm){

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to check that you definitely have an instance of model present within the script. Have you tried creating another function for the sake of testing that will just echo something like "Object is instantiated and inherited functions properly".

That way we might be able to narrow down the problem a little

Comment: This is more a comment than a real answer.

Comment: I ran a quick test. The object is of the right class, and using method_exists I confirmed that the method does exist as well. This error is only appearing once every 20-30 minutes on a site that gets about a visitor a second.